# Difference between compare order of std::sort and priority_queue (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, priority-queue

I am wondering why `priority_queue` and `vector` work the totally different way. Here is the sample:

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, less<int> > pq;
pq.push(1);
pq.push(2);
pq.push(3);
// if we print the elem in pq by pop(), we get 3, 2, 1
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(3);
v.push_back(2);
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), less<int>()); 
// but we get 1, 2, 3 for vector
```

Both `priority_queue` and `vector` used `less`, but why the result is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::less` is the default compartor for `priority_queue`, and `std::vector` is the default Container, so your code can be simplified as:

```cpp
priority_queue<int> pq;
```

According to the [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), it's expected to get the largest value via `pop`

> A priority queue is a container adaptor that provides constant time
> lookup of the largest (by default) element, at the expense of
> logarithmic insertion and extraction.

Actually, we get a `max heap` with `std::less` as a comparator, this doesn't seem very intuitive. To get a `min heap`, we need to use `std::greater` as a comparator.

[Related question to see more underly details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590546/why-does-stdpriority-queue-use-max-heap-instead-of-min-heap#:%7E:text=Priority_queue%20is%20adapted%20from%20make_heap,So%20it%20is%20max%20heap.)

Comment: My question is, why do they work differently? With using the same ```std::less```, ```priority_queue``` gives me descending order, and ```sort``` gives me ascending order(as I expected). Like you said, ```std::less``` is the default, but why do they work the opposite?
Is it just because we think a "heap" as "max heap" by default? Conventionally?

Comment: @J.Victor It's by design, though it's not very intuitive, we get a `max heap`  with std::less as a comparator

Comment: @J.Victor There is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590546/why-does-stdpriority-queue-use-max-heap-instead-of-min-heap#:%7E:text=Priority_queue%20is%20adapted%20from%20make_heap,So%20it%20is%20max%20heap to see more details

Answer (score 1):

The `std::priority_queue` implemented as a heap, it will automatically sort when you insert elements. `less<int>` means it is the max-heap. When you use `pop()` to pop an element, you will get the largest element in the heap.
You can get a more detailed description from cppreference:

> Compare   -   A Compare type providing a strict weak ordering.
> Note that the Compare parameter is defined such that it returns true if its first argument comes before its second argument in a weak ordering. But because the priority queue outputs largest elements first, the elements that "come before" are actually output last. That is, the front of the queue contains the "last" element according to the weak ordering imposed by Compare.

[priority_queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)

The `std::sort` is most likely to use QuickSort, `less<int>` means sorts the elements in ascending order.